# php ajax login - undefined index error in php file

Tags: php, ajax, indexing, undefined

I'm doing a php/ajax login, so the page redirect is in javascript (ajax).
I can already redirect it ajax way (w/o connecting to db, etc.),
but when I add the db, and session stuff in php, i got this php error.

[image: Notice: Undefined index: username in D:\wamp\www\bday_app\login.php on line 22]

Here's my code:
I got index.php (which has the login form, and the ajax code),
The ajax code uses login.php (using POST method) to pass the username/password.
Here's the content of my login.php:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query_results)==1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query_results);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['nickname'] = $row['nickname'];
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['middlename'] = $row['middle_name'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['last_name'];
    echo 'Login successful! Redirecting...';
    //header("Location: bday_app_home.php");
}else{
    echo 'Invalid username/ password.';
    //header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Line 22 in the error is:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

If I had an invalid username/password, its fine, coz it will display the message fine in index.php,
but when the username/password is correct, I got this undefined index error.

I don't know why, because username/password was recieved via POST, see the echoed values in the image - mars1, mars123

Please help... :(

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please re-write the error you're getting? this orange background almost made me blind. BTW , what's line 22?

Comment: Show your SQL code? Doesnt seem like the column is "username" or its the session isnt there

Comment: what you get if var_dump($row['username']) ?

Comment: Or just var_dump($row) to make what columns are there?

Comment: Make sure that the key 'username' really does exist in your `$row` result. Has the field perhaps another name?

Comment: thanks..i was so silly. it was named 'event_creator_id'. =D. thanks for letting me know to var_dump($row) :)

Comment: my q'n now is, is this way of doing login secure?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like session problem ....

Have you started the `SESSION`

```
session_start();
```

before

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

Comment: yes, i did. there is session_start(); before i call the db functions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've specified session_start() on top of your script.

Please also make sure that you're not trying to do :

```
echo 'Login successful! Redirecting...';
header("Location: bday_app_home.php");
```

in your script. This will not work, because some output is made before the redirection made by the header() function.

Comment: yes. i already commented the header() func. since i want to do the redirection in javascript